# How to pass a method to instance_eval?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, instance-eval

I want to call `instance_eval` on this class:

```
class A
  attr_reader :att
end
```

passing this method `b`:

```
class B
  def b(*args)
    att
  end
end
```

but this is happening:

```
a = A.new
bb = B.new
a.instance_eval(&bb.method(:b)) # NameError: undefined local variable or method `att' for #<B:0x007fb39ad0d568>
```

When `b` is a block it works, but `b` as a method isn't working. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer does not use a real method as asked, but I didn't need to return a `Proc` or change `A`. This is a DSL, `def_b` should have a meaningful name to the domain, like `configure`, and it is more likely to be defined in a module or base class.

```
class B
  class << self
    def def_b(&block)
      (@b_blocks ||= []) << block
    end

    def run
      return if @b_blocks.nil?
      a = A.new
      @b_blocks.each { |block| a.instance_eval(&block) }
    end
  end

  def_b do
    a
  end
end
```

And it accepts multiple definitions. It could be made accept only a single definition like this:

```
class B
  class << self
    def def_b(&block)
      raise "b defined twice!" unless @b_block.nil?
      @b_block = block
    end

    def run
      A.new.instance_eval(&@b_block) unless @b_block.nil?
    end
  end

  def_b do
    a
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you goal is.  You can easily share methods between classes by defining them in a module and including the module in each class

```
module ABCommon
  def a
    'a'
  end
end

class A
  include ABCommon
end

Anything = Hash
class B < Anything
  include ABCommon

  def b(*args)
    a
  end

  def run
    puts b
  end
end
```

Comment: I want to have state in that class.